# follow and following with status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm working on follow and following functionality with help of this article https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

It's working fine but i added extra column with name status as a boolean which present the follow request has been accepted. **current_user.following** return all relations of current_user but i need those users whose relationship status is true.
My code is totally same as mention article , only i added status column in relationship table.
So kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the original code, but intuitively this should work

```
current_user.following.where(status: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-following):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  .
  .
  .
end
```

So, I think you can do like below to solve your problem:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, ->{ where(status: true) },
                                  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still return all relationships of current_user with status true and false..

Comment: Hi Hoandd. I need your help again. I want to get posts of followed users. Users has many posts and post belongs to user relationship